# How can I make column be first only on mobile only?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Basically, I want the `#heroText` to be First on desktop but then on mobile have it be under the  `#heroImage` column. What would be the best code on Bootstrap 5 to make this work?  I tried doing
`order-sm-first` but it didn't work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="ct-img" class="container-fluid p-0 mb-5" style="background-color:#2F516D;">
  <div class="row d-flex ">
    <div id="heroText" class="col-md-6  col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-white ">
      <div class="hero-left ">
        <h1 class="fw-bold">
          <?php echo  get_field('h1_top_title');?>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="fw-bold">
          <?php echo  get_field('h2_top_title');?>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <?php echo  get_field('top_hero_paragraph');?>
        </p>
        <a href="/contact-us">
          <button class="btn  cta-button zoom tex">Get A Free Consultation</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="heroImage" class=" col-md-6 col-12 p-0 order-sm-first">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="<?php echo $top_image['alt'];?>">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `order-sm-first` class ignores the base or xs breakpoint. You need `order-first`, which you'd then override for the larger breakpoint.

Other tips:

- It's usually not a great idea to put padding classes on your primary layout grid. Your padding on the container is why you have horizontal scrollbars.
- Bootstrap is built on a "mobile first" philosophy, which means that styles are applied for the smallest breakpoint range and overridden for larger ones. You should follow suit with things like your column classes, which should be listed smallest to largest as Bootstrap does in the documentation.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="ct-img" class="container-fluid p-0 mb-5" style="background-color:#2F516D;">
  <div class="row d-flex ">
    <div id="heroText" class="col-md-6  col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-white ">
      <div class="hero-left ">
        <h1 class="fw-bold">
          <?php echo  get_field('h1_top_title');?>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="fw-bold">
          <?php echo  get_field('h2_top_title');?>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <?php echo  get_field('top_hero_paragraph');?>
        </p>
        <a href="/contact-us">
          <button class="btn  cta-button zoom tex">Get A Free Consultation</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="heroImage" class=" col-md-6 col-12 p-0 order-first order-md-2">
      <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000" alt="<?php echo $top_image['alt'];?>">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```